# Automatically send a string when opening a raw connection in putty

Tags: windows, putty

I have a program running on a server that accepts a raw TCP/IP connections on a specified port. When a connection is made, this program waits for the user (i.e. me) to send a string which identifies the type of user.  Once the user identifies themselves, the program will start sending data that is relevant to that user type.  I want to automate the first step and have putty automatically send the user identification string once the connection is made.  I've been through the settings, and can't seem to find anything like "send following commands on connection".  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I just found [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.com/) via one of the [ads](https://meta.superuser.com/a/4071/17529).  Reading through some of the information, it doesn't seem like it will solve my problem, but I'd just like to double check.

Comment: Are you sure PuTTY is still the right tool for this? It's meant for interacting with a remote system. If you just want to send data and get back a response, why don't you just whip up a small script?

Comment: The only other real option is telnet.  PuTTY offers some other advantages over telnet that are beyond the scope of the question.  If they were otherwise equal, I would use telnet, but since they're not, I'd prefer to stick with PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like that, too. Probably we have to wait until [this wish on the PuTTY wishlist](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/scripting.html) is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

i think `telnet` is your tool with input taken from a file

or

`openssl s_client -connect remotehost.com:<port>`

From [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)